# R - sample used in %in% modify dataframe which is being subsetted

Tags: r, subset, sample

Not sure if I titled question correctly, because I don't fully understand the reason of following behaviour:

```
dfSet <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:15, size = 15, replace = FALSE), va1 = NA, va3 = 0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfSet[1:10, ]$va1 <- 'o1'
dfSet[11:15, ]$va1 <- 'o2'

dfSet[dfSet$ID %in% sample(dfSet[dfSet$va1 == 'o1', ]$ID, 7, replace = FALSE), ]$va3 <- 1

print(length(unique(dfSet$ID)))
```

I expect that final print shows 15, but it doesn't. Instead 13 or 14 appears and dfSet is modified in the way, that there are at least two rows with the same ID. It seems that this part of the code:

```
dfSet[dfSet$ID %in% sample(dfSet[dfSet$va1 == 'o1', ]$ID, 7, replace = FALSE), ]$va3 <- 1
```

modify $ID column - I don't know why?

Workaround:

```
temp <- sample(dfSet[dfSet$va1 == 'o1', ]$ID, 7, replace = FALSE)
dfSet[dfSet$ID %in% temp, ]$va3 <- 1
```

In this case everything works as expected - there are 15 rows with unique ID.

The question is why direct usage of sample in %in% modifies data frame?

Comment: Another "work around" would be `dfSet[dfSet$ID %in% sample(dfSet[dfSet$va1 == 'o1', ]$ID, 7, replace = FALSE), "va3"]<-1`. The problem seems to be with the evaluation of both `[<-` and `$<-` although i'm having troubling making a clear example for an answer.

Comment: Are I sure that your "work around" will work in every cases? Or maybe I have to be aware of sth? I am going to use your solution massively (since it is one-liner), thus I would like to be sure that it is OK.

Comment: Yes. Just don't combine `[]` and `$` with `<-`, just use one or their other with a data frame, and you will be safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What seems to be the problem is that that R does some tricky thing when you assign to function return values. For example, something like

```
a <- c(1,3)
names(a) <- c("one", "three")
```

would look very odd in most languages. How do you assign a value to the return value of a function? What's really happening is that there is a function named `names<-` that's defined. Basically that's returning a transformed version of the original object that can then be used to replace the value passed to that function. So it really looks like this

```
.temp. <- `names<-`(a, c("one","three"))
a <- .temp.
```

The variable `a` is always completely replaced, not just it's names.

When you do something like

```
dfSet$a<-1
```

what's really happening again is

```
.temp. <- "$<-"(dfSet, a, 1)
dfSet <- .temp.
```

Now things get a bit more tricky when you try to do both `[]` and `$` subsetting. Look at this sample

```
#for subsetting
f <- function(x,v) {print("testing"); x==v}
x <- rep(0:1, length.out=nrow(dfSet))
dfSet$a <- 0

dfSet[f(x,1),]$a<-1
```

Notice how "testing" is printed twice. What's going on is really more like

```
.temp1. <- "$<-"(dfSet[f(x,1),], a, 1)
.temp2. <- "[<-"(dfSet, f(x,1), , .temp1.)
dfSet <- .temp2.
```

So the `f(x,1)` is evaluated twice. This means that `sample` would be evaluated twice as well.

The error is a bit more obvious is you try to replace a variable that does not exist yet

```
dfSet[f(x,1),]$b<-1
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, f(x, 1), , value = list(ID = c(6L,  :
#  provided 4 variables to replace 3 variables
```

Here you get the warning because the `.temp1.` variable as added the column and now has 4 columns but when you try to do the assignment to `.temp2.` you now have a problem that the slice of the data frame that you are trying to replace is a different size.

The IDs are replaced because the `$<-` operator doesn't just return a new column, it returns a new data.frame with the column updated to whatever value you assigned. This means that the rows that were updated are returned along with the ID that was there when the assignment happened. This is saved in the `.temp1.` variable. Then when you do the `[<-` assignment, you are choosing a new set of rows to swap out. The values of all columns of these rows are replaced with the values from `.temp1.`. This means that you will be overwriting the IDs for the replacement rows and they may differ so you are likely to wind up with two or more copies of a given ID.

Comment: Can you explain why the `ID` column in the example gets overwritten?

Comment: @C_Z_ I tried to add a paragraph to address that question specifically.

Comment: `trace(f)` shows two evaluations, as does `trace(sample)`. This helps to show that sample is indeed evaluated twice.

Comment: I think this belongs in the R inferno

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not 100% sure, I suspect that R is running the `sample` two times. When you subset and assign in R, for example:

```
x[i:j,]$v1 <- 1
```

It gets evaluated as "take out rows i to j from x as a temporary data frame, assign 1 to the v1 column of that data frame, then copy the temporary data frame back into rows i to j in x".

So maybe the indexing expression (i:j) gets executed twice (once to extract, and once to put back), and if it's a random variable, it's going to put the results back in different rows than the ones originally selected.

Comment: I think, indeed, the subsetting expression is being evaluated twice but only, as MrFlick notes, because both `"$<-.data.frame"` and `[<-.data.frame"` are called (in that order). Firstly, a non-saved object (`x[i:j, ]`) is passed to `"$<-"` and its "v1" column is assigned to "1" and then this modified non-saved "data.frame" _as a whole_ is passed to `"[<-"` and assigned to `x[i:j, ]`, so `i:j` is evaluated twice as a subsetting argument.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simpler example:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
x$b <- 5
```

What the second line actually does is

```
x <- `$<-`(x, 'b', 5)
```

You can see that `$<-` is just a function that takes three arguments, an
object, a name and a value. (Note the backticks are necessary if you want to use `$<-` directly.)

The problem I think is that in your example `x` is an expression that
evaluates to different things each time it's evaluated, due to the call to
`sample`, so you should avoid this.

An alternative is to use `[<-` which apparently doesn't have this problem:

```
dfSet[dfSet$ID %in% sample(dfSet[dfSet$va1 == 'o1', ]$ID, 7, replace = FALSE), 'va3'] <- 1
```